# How to convert utf-8 hex to letters with caron in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with saved letters with caron in a MySQL database, because they are saved with UTF-8 hex code, for example "Oja%C4%8Devalec" should be c letter with caron ("Ojačevalec"), but it's saved as %C4%8D.

Example table:

[image: example of latin small letters with caron saved as utf-8 hex]

I tried to transform table to latin1, blob and change it back to utf8

```
alter table my-table change title title TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1;
alter table my-table change title title BLOB;
alter table my-table change title title TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

but without success. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What programming languages do you have available? Apparently MySQL doesn't have a method for this.

Comment: Could you show the `create table` statement of that table?

Comment: Hi, the problem was my collation, becouse it was set up to latin1_swedish_ci, and it should be utf-8. Now i try to change it to urf-8, but letters like %C4%8D wont transform.

Comment: @user1050689 It won't do the transform for you. What you need to do is go through each row in an external program, percent-decode the strings, and then update the row.